# Can an extension provide its own location to a native messaging host?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have an extension that uses native messaging to launch a server. It
sends a message through the native messaging API which launches a host
process; the host process launches an HTTP server on an ephemeral port
and sends the port number back to the extension; the extension then
connects to that port. All of this works fine.

I am attempting to generalize this mechanism in two ways, and cannot
figure out how to do it.

(1) I would like to allow multiple applications to communicate with a
single installed native messaging host. Currently, each application
needs to install its own host which is configured with information
about the application (basically contains all the code for a "server"
for that application). I would like to use a single host which can
serve arbitrary applications.

(2) I would, thus, like to be able to start the process by having the
application connect to the native messaging host and provide it with
the installation directory of the extension. Then I'd like the native
messaging host to be able to read that directory looking for
configuration information, code, etc. so that it can initialize itself
appropriately. Basically, I'd like the native messaging host to be
able to run code and scripts bundled with the extension, in arbitrary
data formats (in my case, probably plain text, JavaScript files, and Java JAR/class
files) to implement the "server" or "native" portion of the
application.

Given that NPAPI plugins are supposed to be re-implemented using the
native messaging API, I am assuming that this is possible and that I
just can't figure out how to do it.

The only approach that I've come up with that might work seems overly
complicated and underperformant -- basically, I believe I could allow
the host to load code from the extension by having the host send a
"request" to the client (by posting a JSON message, with a request ID and a path, say), and having the client use XMLHttpRequest with ArrayBuffer (in the most general case)
to its own chrome-extension:// URL (as obtained by chrome.runtime using the path as the argument to getURL) to
read its files, serializing them back to the host as JSON. Would this
work? Is this the intended approach?

Comment: Just throwing it out there - you're launching an HTTP server, why not communicate with the HTTP server with well.. HTTP? The first app tries to reach it and fails so it launches it, ever other app sees the server running and just talks to it with normal requests.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I don't *want* to start an HTTP server (that's a lot of overhead, including requiring the installation of the HTTP server, to tunnel everything through HTTP, when I could just use the stdio interface that's already there). 

The other problem is, even using HTTP, how can the server use different code for each extension without doing a separate host installation for each extension? The extension can send its own ID, so the server can identify the caller, but I still do not see a way to look up extension-specific configuration and code for that caller.